# Error 400 Update Preview XPM Tridion

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

I'm just finished the configuration of XPM and testing the funcionality I've found a problem with the Update Preview function.
When I use this button I get the following error:

> Unable to update the changes using OData Service.
>   Server remote error: (400) Bad request.
>     Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService Errorcode: 1003 User: NT AUTHORITY\Network Service  StackTrace Information Details:
>      en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      en System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.BatchRequest(Boolean replaceOnUpdate)
>      en System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
>      en Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
>      en Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
>      en SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>      en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

I've configured all following this documentation: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539

It means, XPM extension as a Web Service with the the next IIS configuration:

- IP: XX.X.X.XXX
- Port: 83

The configuration of my `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="7.1"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_dynamic_conf.xsd">
    <URLMappings>
        <StaticMappings>
            <Publications>
                <Publication Id="5">
                    <Host Domain="10.0.9.113" Port="84" Protocol="http" Path=""/>
                </Publication>
            </Publications>
        </StaticMappings>
        <StorageMapping IdentifyPublicationByProperty="publicationUrl"/>
    </URLMappings>
    <TCDLEngine>
        <Properties>
            <Property Name="prop1" Value="value1"/>
            <Property Name="prop2" Value="value2"/>
        </Properties>
    </TCDLEngine>
</Configuration>
```

My `cd_ambient_conf.xml` code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Configuration Version="7.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd">
    <Security>        
    </Security>
  <ExcludedPaths>
  </ExcludedPaths>
  <Cartridges>
    <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
    <Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
  </Cartridges>
</Configuration>
```

My `cd_storage_conf.xml` code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="7.1"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <Global>
        <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
            <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
            </Policy>
            <Features>
                <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>
        </ObjectCache>
        <Storages>
            <StorageBindings>
                <Bundle src="preview_dao_bundle.xml"/>
            </StorageBindings>
            <Wrappers>
                <Wrapper Name="SessionWrapper">
                    <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
                        <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                        <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                            <Property Name="serverName" Value="SERVER_NAME" />
                            <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                            <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_EM" />
                            <Property Name="user" Value="TBEMUser" />
                            <Property Name="password" Value="XXXXXXX" />
                        </DataSource>
                    </Storage>                       
                </Wrapper>
            </Wrappers>
            <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
                <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="SERVER_NAME" />
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                    <Property Name="user" Value="TBUser" />
                    <Property Name="password" Value="XXXX" />
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
                <Root Path="C:\Publicaciones" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
                <Root Path="C:\Publicaciones\data" />
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
    </Global>
    <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultDataFile" cached="false">
        <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
    </ItemTypes>
</Configuration>
```

My publication target is configured like that:

- Content Delivery Endpoint URL: http://10.0.9.113:85/odata.svc
- Website URL's: http://localhost:84/

when I call my ODataService (http://10.0.9.113:85/odata.svc/) it return me the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="http://10.0.9.113:85/odata.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <workspace>
        <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
        <collection href="Binaries">
            <atom:title>Binaries</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Keywords">
            <atom:title>Keywords</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="BinaryContents">
            <atom:title>BinaryContents</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Publications">
            <atom:title>Publications</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="PageContents">
            <atom:title>PageContents</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Templates">
            <atom:title>Templates</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Schemas">
            <atom:title>Schemas</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="StructureGroups">
            <atom:title>StructureGroups</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="CustomMetas">
            <atom:title>CustomMetas</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Components">
            <atom:title>Components</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Pages">
            <atom:title>Pages</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="ComponentPresentations">
            <atom:title>ComponentPresentations</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="BinaryVariants">
            <atom:title>BinaryVariants</atom:title>
        </collection>
    </workspace>
</service>
```

Do you know what could be the problem? Is any configuration wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you configure your Publication Target in CM?

Comment: I've edited my question to add tthe information you are asking.

Comment: The content delivery end point URL in the publication target should have a trailing slash 'http://10.0.9.113:85/odata.svc/'. Are you able to access the ODATA service from the CM and the Presentation servers?

Comment: I've eddited my question with the result of call my service.